# Устройство в Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как в Xcode 9 в main.storyboard выбрать для отображения iPhone 6?
Внизу среди доступных его нет(см скрин).
cmd+alt+enter --> manual --> preview --> "+" я пробовал,
там в списке устройств выпадают такие же

[image: скрин]

Comment: А какая разница 6 или 8?

Comment: затупил) спасибо)